# How do i connect Azure Pipelines in one instance of Azure Devops to an Azure Repo in a separate instance of Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-repos

Any recommendations on how to connect Azure Pipelines in one instance of Azure Devops to an Azure Repo in a separate instance of Azure Devops.

I presume i'd use "Other Git" as the code source but i wanted to see if anyone had any suggestion around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i connect Azure Pipelines in one instance of Azure Devops to an Azure Repo in a separate instance of Azure Devops

You are on the right way! If you want to build the Azure repo in another separate instance of Azure Devops, you should use the "**Other Git**" as the code source.

According to the document [Pipeline options for Git repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops):

> While editing a pipeline that uses a Git repo (in an Azure DevOps or
>   TFS project, GitHub, GitHub Enterprise Server, Bitbucket Cloud, or
>   another Git repo),

So, we could use the latest option, the **another Git repo**.

Details:

- Click `Other Git` and add `new service connection`:

[image]

- Add the `Git repository URL` and the `PAT` of that repo.
- Click OK button to save the connection.

As test, I could build the project in another Azure Repo.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help